# ModuleNotFoundError: No module names libcloud.utils

Tags: python, linux, windows, operating-system, libcloud

Using python 3.7.9, apache-libcloud 3.6.0

It was working fine on Ubuntu however error arose when replicating on Windows therefore guessing it is OS problem however cannot find any reference online.

When I call get_driver() method from `libcloud.storage.providers` it attempts and fails to `import libcloud.utils`

```
from libcloud.storage.types import Provider
from libcloud.storage.providers import get_driver

driver_class = get_driver(Provider.S3)
```

Error message:
`line 26, in <module> import libcloud.utils.py3 ModuleNotFoundError: No module names 'libcloud.utils'`

EDIT: After installing libcloud library when I navigate to its folder it is missing `utils` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Install `dj-libcloud` from terminal using `pip`.

The command:

```
pip install dj-libcloud
```

Then try:

```
import libcloud.utils
```

Comment: Could you explain why installing dj-libcloud helps?

Comment: You may using older version of `dj-libcloud`. So updating it again should help. Also your given example is similar in this [docs](https://libcloud.readthedocs.io/en/stable/storage/examples.html).

Comment: isn't dj-libcloud was a wrapper for apache-libcloud? Also why does it work on linux but no windows...?

Comment: Yes. It a wrapper for `apache-libcloud`. And I haven't tried it on windows but I think there are some compatibility issue with `dj-libcloud` on windows.

Comment: When I  install apache-libcloud utils folder isn't in the downloaded library.